# act_as_taggable_on templates /css : Rails tag cloud

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tags, responsive-design, tag-cloud

I am using act_as_taggable_on gem to generate tags on my Rails4 app.

The basic css is very basic :

```
#tag_cloud {
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  .s { font-size: 0.8em; }
  .m { font-size: 1.2em; }
  .l { font-size: 1.8em; }
}
```

Are there any other examples of styles that we can use with act_as_taggable_on gem. Something like these:
http://www.google.com/imgres?sa=X&espv=210&es_sm=119&biw=1920&bih=1000&tbm=isch&tbnid=MZw34eJzj-5q4M:&imgrefurl=http://criminology.pbworks.com/w/page/12518021/Tag%2520Clouds&docid=8U7gpiT_E5EnhM&imgurl=http://criminology.pbworks.com/f/1232484379/tagcloud.jpg&w=813&h=405&ei=_DK-UsGRMJPnoASYw4KYCg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:16,s:0,i:150&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=159&tbnw=319&start=0&ndsp=27&tx=236&ty=34

http://www.google.com/imgres?sa=X&espv=210&es_sm=119&biw=1920&bih=1000&tbm=isch&tbnid=qkERvC64ASOVZM:&imgrefurl=http://torquemag.io/tag-cloud-plugin-names/&docid=36WNrnVr9gLQYM&imgurl=http://3j68xu1tybju34n8yb4fm4b189a.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/wordpress-tag-cloud-plugin-names.png&w=1920&h=1080&ei=_DK-UsGRMJPnoASYw4KYCg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:2,s:0,i:108&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=168&tbnw=300&start=0&ndsp=27&tx=130&ty=69

Tech stack:
Coffeescript, Heroku, Rails4, Ruby2.0, haml, scss, bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`d3`](https://github.com/logical42/d3_rails) library along with [`d3-cloud`](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) plugin.